# How can I align the tops of two paragraphs in this example without resorting to an empty header? (e.g., <h2>&nbsp;</h2>)

Tags: html, css

Given two side-by-side boxes on a webpage — one containing a header and a paragraph, and the other containing *only* a paragraph — how can I align the tops of the paragraphs using pure HTML/CSS? i.e., without resorting to using an empty header (e.g., `<h2>&nbsp;</h2>`) or JavaScript?

Here's a jsfiddle illustrating the conundrum:
http://jsfiddle.net/y5gpe/

Estimating the appropriate `margin-top` for the headerless paragraph (as seen in the jsfiddle above) seems to be an exercise in futility, since different browsers always have slight variations in font size. There's no way to get them to perfectly align. Case in point: The jsfiddle above is perfectly aligned in Chrome, but it's off by 3px in Firefox:

[image]

Is the only way to do this to create an ugly empty header in the markup of the headerless box? This is a problem that I regularly encounter in HTML/CSS, and I'm wondering if other developers have a more elegant way of handling it.

Comment: U can put the h2 in e.g. a DIV, or (not as neat) use a table or worse and discouraged make h2 position:absolute. Also u can have browser specific css but in this case u can have a cleaner fix with Box-lvl elem: DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that you can't change the HTML code, or indeed that the header is only relevant to the left column and not the right, you could use a `:before` pseudo element on the `.no-header` and create a 'space' that has the same styles as the `<h2>` in the column next door.

Lets say the h2 has the following styles explicitly set:

```
h2 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Then we could mimic that in the pseudo element on the `.no-header` element:

```
p.no-header:before {
  content: '\a0'; /* A SPACE */
  display: block; /* block level, like a <h2> element */
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold; /* Not sure if this makes a difference, but just in case */
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y5gpe/7/)**

Comment: Clever! Thanks for sharing. (And your assumption was correct: I cannot change the HTML, so that's why this workaround is especially great.)

Answer (score 1):

On suggestion would be using multiple rows instead of simply two columns. So instead of two columns use two rows with only the first column or a full width column for the header. Then use a two column row for the actual text content. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y5gpe/3/). This might of course add implications of it's own though.

**Illustration**

```
----------------------
| Header             |
----------------------
| Col-1    | Col-2   |
----------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had the same thought, but what if (as in the jsfiddle example) the two boxes have a visible border between them? Seems like this method breaks down then.

Comment: @Michael It's still possible to achieve the borders, but it is a lot harder.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and stick the Header outside of the box class, 
and wrap everything in a container:

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
    <h2>Header text</h2>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ornare nunc sed lectus commodo faucibus a a purus. Curabitur sit amet placerat diam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ornare nunc sed lectus commodo faucibus a a purus. Curabitur sit amet placerat diam.</p>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:
.box {
    float: left;
    border: 0; 
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    border: 1px solid #888;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Similar problem as in Hugo's answer though (see my comment): If there's a border between the two boxes, this solution unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: If that's the case, you could remove the border in the box class:
border: 0;
and add overflow hidden to the container.